# Gluon Scene Builder installed but not opening in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, scenebuilder, gluon-desktop

I have installed the Gluon Scene Builder in Ubuntu 17.04, to use it with NetBeans.

Gluon works normally outside NetBeans and the Oracle Scene Builder also worked fine before installing Gluon.

After installing Gluon, the right-click option on the fxml file still has the option "Open", but clicking on it doesn't open the Gluon Scene Builder.

In the System Monitor, I can see that the process is actually running, but inside NetBeans, the Gluon Window does not open. Killing the process and clicking on the Scene Builder icon the application list (outside NetBeans) does open Gluon.

There are no error messages.

In NetBeans options, the Scene Builder Home is defined as Default (opt/SceneBuilder). This seems to be correct, since the process in the System Monitor points to this location.

Any idea what I am missing? A hint would be appreciated.

This is the stacktrace :

```
INFO: Start exploring JAR /home/rainer/.scenebuilder/Library/charm-0.0.2.jar
nov 26, 2017 11:14:03 PM com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp$SceneBuilderUncaughtExceptionHandler uncaughtException
SEVERE: An exception was thrown:
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.get(ObservableListWrapper.java:89)
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList.get(Collections.java:1309)
at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.lambda$handleLaunch$5(SceneBuilderApp.java:409)
at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.exploreAndUpdateLibrary(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:356)
at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.runDiscovery(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:138)
at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.run(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:92)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

nov 26, 2017 11:14:06 PM com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp logTimestamp
INFO: JavaFX Scene Builder started
```

Comment: Find out the path where you have installed Gluon Scene Builder and make sure that NetBeans (8.2?) options point to it.

Comment: Gluon is definitely installed in the /opt/SceneBuilder directory. Still, it doenst't open from within NetBeans. Running /opt/SceneBuilder/SceneBuilder from the command line runs it smoothly ...

Comment: Having the same problem with NetBeans and Scene Builder in Ubuntu. My installation is also in /opt/SceneBuilder but Netbeans does not like that path. Did you figure it out? (I know it was ages ago though)